# vkCreateGraphicsPipelines segfault's in shared library but not in static library

Tags: c, vulkan

I'm trying to write a shared library (in c) which is supposed to initiate vulkan (among other things). By initiating I mean it should do the whole setup-chain ranging from instance creation to pipeline creation.

When I call the aforementioned function as a static library function -> everything works and there is no  segfault occurring in vkCreateGraphicsPipelines. However, when I build the same function as a shared (.so) library and call it -> vkCreateGraphicsPipelines segfault's.

## Update 07.03.19

Validation Layers are now running on full steam.

#### Compilation with static lib:

```
gcc test.c -lvulkan -lglfw -lvui_static
```

Callback output regarding pipeline creation (function exits normally):

```
creating pipeline!
Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, pipelineCache, createInfoCount, pCreateInfos, pAllocator, pPipelines) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    device:                         VkDevice = 0x559b52daf3a0
    pipelineCache:                  VkPipelineCache = 0
    createInfoCount:                uint32_t = 1
    pCreateInfos:                   const VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo* = 0x559b52cd57f8
        pCreateInfos[0]:                const VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo = 0x559b52cd57f8:
            sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO (28)
            pNext:                          const void* = NULL
            flags:                          VkPipelineCreateFlags = 0
            stageCount:                     uint32_t = 2
            pStages:                        const VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo* = 0x559b52cd8058
                pStages[0]:                     const VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo = 0x559b52cd8058:
                    sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO (18)
                    pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                    flags:                          VkPipelineShaderStageCreateFlags = 0
                    stage:                          VkShaderStageFlagBits = 1 (VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS | VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL)
                    module:                         VkShaderModule = 0x559b52cd8910
                    pName:                          const char* = "main"
                    pSpecializationInfo:            const VkSpecializationInfo* = NULL
                pStages[1]:                     const VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo = 0x559b52cd8088:
                    sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO (18)
                    pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                    flags:                          VkPipelineShaderStageCreateFlags = 0
                    stage:                          VkShaderStageFlagBits = 16 (VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS | VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL)
                    module:                         VkShaderModule = 0x559b52dcc6b0
                    pName:                          const char* = "main"
                    pSpecializationInfo:            const VkSpecializationInfo* = NULL
            pVertexInputState:              const VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52dcf790:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO (19)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateFlags = 0
                vertexBindingDescriptionCount:  uint32_t = 0
                pVertexBindingDescriptions:     const VkVertexInputBindingDescription* = NULL
                vertexAttributeDescriptionCount: uint32_t = 0
                pVertexAttributeDescriptions:   const VkVertexInputAttributeDescription* = NULL
            pInputAssemblyState:            const VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52dcf030:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO (20)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateFlags = 0
                topology:                       VkPrimitiveTopology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST (3)
                primitiveRestartEnable:         VkBool32 = 0
            pTessellationState:             const VkPipelineTessellationStateCreateInfo* = NULL
            pViewportState:                 const VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52dcf140:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO (22)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineViewportStateCreateFlags = 0
                viewportCount:                  uint32_t = 1
                pViewports:                     const VkViewport* = 0x559b52dc8e70
                    pViewports[0]:                  const VkViewport = 0x559b52dc8e70:
                        x:                              float = 0
                        y:                              float = 0
                        width:                          float = 500
                        height:                         float = 500
                        minDepth:                       float = 0
                        maxDepth:                       float = 1
                scissorCount:                   uint32_t = 1
                pScissors:                      const VkRect2D* = 0x559b52dc94f0
                    pScissors[0]:                   const VkRect2D = 0x559b52dc94f0:
                        offset:                         VkOffset2D = 0x559b52dc94f0:
                            x:                              int32_t = 0
                            y:                              int32_t = 0
                        extent:                         VkExtent2D = 0x559b52dc94f8:
                            width:                          uint32_t = 500
                            height:                         uint32_t = 500
            pRasterizationState:            const VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52dca7a0:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO (23)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateFlags = 0
                depthClampEnable:               VkBool32 = 0
                rasterizerDiscardEnable:        VkBool32 = 0
                polygonMode:                    VkPolygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL (0)
                cullMode:                       VkCullModeFlags = 2 (VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT | VK_CULL_MODE_FRONT_AND_BACK)
                frontFace:                      VkFrontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE (1)
                depthBiasEnable:                VkBool32 = 0
                depthBiasConstantFactor:        float = 0
                depthBiasClamp:                 float = 0
                depthBiasSlopeFactor:           float = 0
                lineWidth:                      float = 1
            pMultisampleState:              const VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52dc93e0:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO (24)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateFlags = 0
                rasterizationSamples:           VkSampleCountFlagBits = 1 (VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT)
                sampleShadingEnable:            VkBool32 = 0
                minSampleShading:               float = 0
                pSampleMask:                    const VkSampleMask* = NULL
                alphaToCoverageEnable:          VkBool32 = 0
                alphaToOneEnable:               VkBool32 = 0
            pDepthStencilState:             const VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo* = NULL
            pColorBlendState:               const VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo* = 0x559b52cd6f90:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO (26)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateFlags = 0
                logicOpEnable:                  VkBool32 = 0
                logicOp:                        VkLogicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY (3)
                attachmentCount:                uint32_t = 1
                pAttachments:                   const VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState* = 0x559b52dcf0a0
                    pAttachments[0]:                const VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState = 0x559b52dcf0a0:
                        blendEnable:                    VkBool32 = 0
                        srcColorBlendFactor:            VkBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO (0)
                        dstColorBlendFactor:            VkBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO (0)
                        colorBlendOp:                   VkBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD (0)
                        srcAlphaBlendFactor:            VkBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO (0)
                        dstAlphaBlendFactor:            VkBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO (0)
                        alphaBlendOp:                   VkBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD (0)
                        colorWriteMask:                 VkColorComponentFlags = 15 (VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT)
                blendConstants:                 float[4] = 0x559b52cd6fb8
                    blendConstants[0]:              float = 0
                    blendConstants[1]:              float = 0
                    blendConstants[2]:              float = 0
                    blendConstants[3]:              float = 0
            pDynamicState:                  const VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo* = NULL
            layout:                         VkPipelineLayout = 0x559b52cd6de0
            renderPass:                     VkRenderPass = 0x559b52c582d0
            subpass:                        uint32_t = 0
            basePipelineHandle:             VkPipeline = 0
            basePipelineIndex:              int32_t = 0
    pAllocator:                     const VkAllocationCallbacks* = NULL
    pPipelines:                     VkPipeline* = 0x559b528e53e0
        pPipelines[0]:                  VkPipeline = 0x559b52dcaa60

pipeline created!
```

#### Compilation with shared lib:

```
gcc test.c -lvulkan -lglfw -lvui
```

Callback output regarding pipeline creation (function exits abnormally -> no api dump):

```
creating pipeline!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

gdb backtrace:

```
Thread 1 "a.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7d1549a in crc32 () from /usr/local/lib/libvui.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7d1549a in crc32 () from /usr/local/lib/libvui.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff5fb252f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#2  0x00007ffff5fac515 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#3  0x00007ffff5e42d13 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#4  0x00007ffff5e403d3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#5  0x00007ffff5e41bbb in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#6  0x00007ffff5e6ce44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libvulkan_intel.so
#7  0x00007ffff5454aff in vkCreateGraphicsPipelines ()
```

### vui_vulkanInit.c (calls vkCreateGraphicsPipeline()):

```
#include "../vui_vulkanInit.h"
#include "../vui_debug.h"

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void initVulkan() 
{
// handles 
    GLFWwindow* window;
    VkInstance *instance               = malloc(sizeof(VkInstance));
    VkSurfaceKHR *surface              = malloc(sizeof(VkSurfaceKHR));
    VkPhysicalDevice *physicalDevice   = malloc(sizeof(VkPhysicalDevice));
    VkDevice *device                   = malloc(sizeof(VkDevice));
    VkQueue *graphicsQueue             = malloc(sizeof(VkQueue));
    VkSwapchainKHR *swapChain          = malloc(sizeof(VkSwapchainKHR));
    VkImage *swapChainImages           = malloc(sizeof(VkImage) * 3);
    VkFormat *swapChainImageFormat     = malloc(sizeof(VkFormat));
    VkExtent2D *swapChainExtent        = malloc(sizeof(VkExtent2D));
    VkImageView *swapChainImageViews   = malloc(sizeof(VkImageView) * 3);
    VkRenderPass *renderPass           = malloc(sizeof(VkRenderPass));
    VkPipelineLayout *pipelineLayout   = malloc(sizeof(VkPipelineLayout));
    VkPipeline *graphicsPipeline       = malloc(sizeof(VkPipeline));
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT *callback = malloc(sizeof(VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT));

    if (errno == ENOMEM)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

// glfw window
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Vulkan", VK_NULL_HANDLE, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

    if (!window)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

// instance
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName   = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName        = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion      = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion         = VK_API_VERSION_1_1;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = {};
    instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    // validation layers
        const char *validationLayers[2] = {"VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation", "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump"};
        instanceInfo.enabledLayerCount   = 2;
        instanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers;

    // extensions
        char *ext1_p = VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME;

        uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
        glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);
        uint32_t totalExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount + 1;
        const char **glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

        const char *extensions[totalExtensionCount];
        extensions[0] = ext1_p;
        for (int i = 1; i < glfwExtensionCount + 1; ++i)
            extensions[i] = glfwExtensions[i - 1];

        instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount   = totalExtensionCount;
        instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions;

    VK_ASSERT(vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, instance));

// validation callback
    vui_createVulkanMessenger(*instance, callback);

// surface
    VK_ASSERT(glfwCreateWindowSurface(*instance, window, VK_NULL_HANDLE, surface));

// physical device
    uint32_t deviceCount = 0;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*instance, &deviceCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    VkPhysicalDevice devices[deviceCount];
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*instance, &deviceCount, devices);
    // there is only one device possible because I have no dedicated gpu
    for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i) {
        physicalDevice = &(devices[i]);
        break;
    }

// device
    uint32_t queueFamilyIndex = 0;

    float queuePriority = 1.0f;
    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueCreateInfo = {};
    queueCreateInfo.sType            = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    queueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = queueFamilyIndex;
    queueCreateInfo.queueCount       = 1;
    queueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority;

    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures = {};
    const char *deviceExtensions = VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceInfo = {};
    deviceInfo.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    deviceInfo.queueCreateInfoCount    = 1;
    deviceInfo.pQueueCreateInfos       = &queueCreateInfo;
    deviceInfo.pEnabledFeatures        = &deviceFeatures;
    deviceInfo.enabledExtensionCount   = 1;
    deviceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = &deviceExtensions;
    deviceInfo.enabledLayerCount       = 0;

    VK_ASSERT(vkCreateDevice(*physicalDevice, &deviceInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, device));
    vkGetDeviceQueue(*device, queueFamilyIndex, 0, graphicsQueue);

// swapchain
    VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR capabilities;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(*physicalDevice, *surface, &capabilities);
    uint32_t formatCount;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*physicalDevice, *surface, &formatCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    VkSurfaceFormatKHR formats[formatCount];
    if (formatCount != 0)
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*physicalDevice, *surface, &formatCount, formats);

    // these assumptions are fine for the purpose of debugging
    VkSurfaceFormatKHR surfaceFormat = formats[1];
    VkPresentModeKHR presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR;
    VkExtent2D extent = capabilities.currentExtent;
    uint32_t imageCount = 3;

    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchainInfo = {};
    swapchainInfo.sType                 = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapchainInfo.surface               = *surface;
    swapchainInfo.minImageCount         = imageCount;
    swapchainInfo.imageFormat           = surfaceFormat.format;
    swapchainInfo.imageColorSpace       = surfaceFormat.colorSpace;
    swapchainInfo.imageExtent           = extent;
    swapchainInfo.imageArrayLayers      = 1;
    swapchainInfo.imageUsage            = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    swapchainInfo.imageSharingMode      = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapchainInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;
    swapchainInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices   = &queueFamilyIndex;
    swapchainInfo.preTransform          = capabilities.currentTransform;
    swapchainInfo.compositeAlpha        = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    swapchainInfo.presentMode           = presentMode;
    swapchainInfo.clipped               = VK_TRUE;
    swapchainInfo.oldSwapchain          = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    VK_ASSERT(vkCreateSwapchainKHR(*device, &swapchainInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, swapChain));
    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(*device, *swapChain, &imageCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(*device, *swapChain, &imageCount, swapChainImages);
    *swapChainImageFormat = surfaceFormat.format;
    *swapChainExtent      = extent;

// render pass

    // ! Please note: structs abstracted.

    VK_ASSERT(vkCreateRenderPass(*device, &renderPassInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, renderPass));

// pipeline layout
    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo = {};
    pipelineLayoutInfo.sType                  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount         = 0;
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;

    VK_ASSERT(vkCreatePipelineLayout(*device, &pipelineLayoutInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, pipelineLayout));

// pipeline
    const uint32_t vs_code[] = 
    {
        #include "absPath"
    };
    VkShaderModule vertShaderModule = createShaderModule(*device, vs_code, sizeof(vs_code));
    const uint32_t fs_code[] = 
    {
        #include "absPath"
    };
    VkShaderModule fragShaderModule = createShaderModule(*device, fs_code, sizeof(fs_code));

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertShaderStageInfo = {};
    vertShaderStageInfo.sType  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertShaderStageInfo.stage  = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    vertShaderStageInfo.module = vertShaderModule;
    vertShaderStageInfo.pName  = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragShaderStageInfo = {};
    fragShaderStageInfo.sType  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    fragShaderStageInfo.stage  = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    fragShaderStageInfo.module = fragShaderModule;
    fragShaderStageInfo.pName  = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = {vertShaderStageInfo, fragShaderStageInfo};

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {};
    vertexInputInfo.sType                           = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount   = 0;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
    inputAssembly.sType                  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssembly.topology               = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.x        = 0.0f;
    viewport.y        = 0.0f;
    viewport.width    = (float) (*swapChainExtent).width;
    viewport.height   = (float) (*swapChainExtent).height;
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

    VkOffset2D offset;
    offset.x = 0;
    offset.y = 0;
    VkRect2D scissor = {};
    scissor.offset = offset;
    scissor.extent = *swapChainExtent;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
    viewportState.sType         = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.pViewports    = &viewport;
    viewportState.scissorCount  = 1;
    viewportState.pScissors     = &scissor;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable        = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode             = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.lineWidth               = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode                = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace               = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable         = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
    multisampling.sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable  = VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
    colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable    = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
    colorBlending.sType             = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.logicOpEnable     = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlending.logicOp           = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
    colorBlending.attachmentCount   = 1;
    colorBlending.pAttachments      = &colorBlendAttachment;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType               = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount          = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages             = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState   = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState      = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState   = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState    = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout              = *pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass          = *renderPass;
    pipelineInfo.subpass             = 0;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle  = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    printf("creating pipeline!\n");
    VK_ASSERT(vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(*device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, graphicsPipeline));
    printf("pipeline created!\n");
}

VkShaderModule createShaderModule(VkDevice device, const uint32_t *code, size_t size) {
    VkShaderModule module;
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shaderCreateInfo = 
    {
        .sType    = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext    = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
        .flags    = 0,
        .codeSize = size,
        .pCode    = code,
    };
    vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shaderCreateInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &module);
    return module;
}

static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity, VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT *pCallbackData, void *pUserData) 
{
    printf("%s\n", pCallbackData->pMessage);
    return VK_FALSE;
}

static void vui_createVulkanMessenger(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT *callback) 
{
    PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT funcPointer = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    EXIT_ON_NULL(funcPointer);
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugUtilsMessengerInfo = 
    {
        .sType           = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT,
        .pNext           = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
        .flags           = 0,
        .messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT,
        .messageType     = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT,
        .pfnUserCallback = debugCallback,
        .pUserData       = VK_NULL_HANDLE
    };
    VK_ASSERT(funcPointer(instance, &debugUtilsMessengerInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, callback));
}
```

Thank you for reading this, Ojad

Comment: Do not describe code, show it. Both versions, the problem-free non-lib version and the problematic lib version. Also explain in detail how you build. Preferrably provide the commandline/makefile.

Comment: Shared library is code as any other. Only differs in linking. How do you load shaders?

Comment: Thank you for your criticism @Yunnosch. I hope it's better now.

Comment: @krOoze I load the shaders exactly like the cube.c example from the vulkan-sdk. Thank you for answering me!

Comment: Where does `pipelineLayoutInfo` come from?

Comment: @solidpixel I've updated the source code. It's a very simple setup and I omitted a lot to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: @krOoze maybe the backtrace (please see the updated question) sheds some light on the issue.

Comment: The backtrace looks weird to me. There's not even the Vulkan Loader present in it. Not to mention the validation layers...

Comment: BTW, you are not checking if the `malloc`s succeeded. GLFW errco is also not checked. Some commands are not checked for `VkResult`.

Comment: Maybe try the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` layer so we see what actually goes in and out.

Comment: Variables used in `pipelineInfo` do not even exist. Is this some kind of pseudocode?

Comment: @krOoze yes it is, (notice the // ...structs abstracted). I thought that it doesn't matter because the code seems to be fine when compiling as a static lib. I will update the question once I tried all your suggestions. I will also post the code without any abstractions (it probably was a bad idea anyway - verbose is king when it comes to debugging - sorry about that). Thank you so much!

Comment: @krOoze I posted the complete code (without renderpass structs due to char limitation) and activated the api dump layer. I also updated the gdb backtrace. Unfortunately still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segfault in

```
#0  0x00007ffff7fc37db in crc32 () from /usr/local/lib/libvui.so.0
```

was caused by a declaration conflict. Basically, I included a lib which contained a function called crc32. There must be a function with the same declaration somewhere in libvulkan_intel.so or at least somewhere as an outside dependency. Either way, when compiling as a shared library I was effectively overriding crc32 which resulted in a segfault as soon as crc32 was called.. not my proudest bug but it happens.